# error prototype does not match any in class

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, bubble-sort

I am facing a problem running this on NetBeans.
Here is my class for a Bubble Sorting algorithm including the main function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <class elemType>
class arrayListType
{
public:
    void BubbleSort();

private:
    elemType list[100];
    int length;
    void swap(int first, int second);
    void BubbleUp(int startIndex, int endIndex);
    void print();
    void insert();
};

template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::BubbleUp(int startIndex, int endIndex)
{

for (int index = startIndex; index < endIndex ; index++){
    if(list[index] > list[index+1])
        swap(index,index+1);
}
} 

template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::swap(int first, int second)
{

elemType temp;
temp = list[first];
list[first] = list[second];
list[second] = temp;
} 

template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::insert()
{
cout<<"please type in the length: ";
cin>>length;
cout<<"please enter "<<length<<" numbers"<< endl;
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    cin>>list[i];
}
}

template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::print()
{
    cout<<"the sorted numbers" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        cout<<list[i]<<endl;        
    }
}
```

The error is represented in this function declaration:

```
template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::BubbleSort(elemType list[], int numvalues)
{
    insert();
    int current=0;
    numvalues--;

    while(current < numvalues)
    {
        BubbleUp(current,numvalues);
        numvalues--;
    }

    print();
}
```

the main function:

```
    int main()
    {
    arrayListType<int> list ;
    list.BubbleSort();

    }
```

I did another sorting algorithm before but it worked well. How can I really fix this prototyping match thing ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::BubbleSort(elemType list[], int numvalues)
```

In your class, you wrote a *prototype* for the method, like this:

```
void BubbleSort();
```

This doesn't match:

```
BubbleSort(elemType list[], int numvalues)
```

To solve the error, remove the parameters from the actual implementation, or add the parameters to the prototype. Your error is self-explanatory, it is complaining about a prototype not matching a definition.